# how to grab the value via a selector and manipulate it inline

Tags: jquery

Sorry if subject isn't very descriptive.

Say for example I have this:

```
// lets update the count
<div class='user-count'>3</div>

$('.user-count')val().text(x + 1);
```

so that it becomes:

```
<div class='user-count'>4</div>
```

thx

Comment: thx for quick answers. I guess that was really simple

Comment: it is pretty basic but as you can see from the answers, there is more than one way to do it! No harm in asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch the current value with [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/), parse the value as an integer, add one, and then set again the `text()`:

```
var $userCount = $(".user-count");
$userCount.text(parseInt($userCount.text()) + 1);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6Mnja/)**.

Answer (score 1):

`.val()` is only used for form elements...

In this case, you'd need to use `.html()` to get the contents, `parseInt()` to turn it into a number and then modify it, and again `.html()` to add it back to the `div`.

Like this:

```
var $uC = $(".user-count");
val = parseInt($uC.html());
$uC.html(val+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

`val` method is used for getting/setting value of form controls, for other elements you should use `text` or `html`, try the following:

```
$('.user-count').text(function(i, x){
    return parseInt(x, 10) + 1
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xqjHk/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.user-count').text(function(index, val){
  return parseInt(val) + 1;
});
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MqRBd/1/)